# (Why) does CV post comments under my name and without notifying me?

Tags: support, comment

While I was interacting with [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576399), I noticed that the author incorporated the comments to ask an [equivalent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576511) (instead of editing the original one).

Since I think that this constituted a duplicate, I flagged the equivalent question as duplicate and provided a link to the original question.

Now when I go to the comment section of the original question, there is a new comment under my name which I did not write, which roughly reads:

> Does this answer your question? [link to equivalent question by same author]

I did not write this comment myself. It is a nonsensical comment, since the author should know about his second question anyways. So why did CV post this **in my name** and **without notifying me**?

Comment: Far from being nonsensical, that construction is a polite way of letting the author know that we are aware of their repeated posts on the same topic.  BTW, you can see that comment appear immediately after you vote to close and, at any time, you have the option to delete it.  (I have often done this after my own votes.)  I realize that's an imperfect solution, but it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what the software does when a user proposes that a question is a duplicate. The software isn't smart enough to figure out the contextual information about who authored which question, and the relationships among the authors.

The main meta.stackexchange site is the best place to ask questions about how the Stack Exchange software works. Here's the duplicate thread: [The auto-comment “Does this answer your question?” generated when voting to close as a duplicate is sometimes confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/the-auto-comment-does-this-answer-your-question-generated-when-voting-to-clos)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. That explains why I did find nothing in the CV help pages.